# Heating and Battery problem 15" Macbook Pro i5 hr antiglare screen

Tags: macbook

Well my battery is only lasting for 4.5 hours or 4 hours if I have Xcode open, and sometimes if I'm using youtube (which will make safari to use 15% of the processor) the heat can go up to 145 F or 62 C. Not saying that sometimes can be uncomfortable to hold it on my lap... because of the heat...

Is this normal? 
Should I take it to warranty?

Thank you!

Comment: Its a MBP, totally normal. Next time get a PC or bear with this. (Read about the MBP i7 overheating. Cool. :))

Comment: Take it to the store and recreate the scenario for them. It's not normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's worth calling AppleCare about.

By the way, you might save some CPU cycles by opting into [YouTube's HTML5 beta](http://youtube.com/html5), and by installing [ClickToFlash](http://clicktoflash.com/).

Comment: I second ClickToFlash.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. 4.5 Hours is probably pretty normal for your usage, as wifi is generally a drain on the battery, not to mention streaming flash isn't helping you either.

Notebooks generally take more heat instead of turning on the fans, so 145F is not bad (I think the max temp on the Macbooks is somewhere around 200F - I know it is really high)

This is also why now, these are called "Notebooks" instead of "Laptops" - because they are becoming hot, and are now designed to sit on a table or something instead of your lap.

Here are some CPU temp readings from others: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=261536